# How can I get server date and time in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Local system time and date may be wrong. Hence I want server time and date in my AngularJs project but I can't find a solution yet.
How do I get the server date and time?

Comment: You would need to expose it to the client side, in which *how* is entirely dependent on the server side.

Comment: You need http call for get the server side method, that returns server side date

Comment: Which server and server side language do you use?

Comment: i am using heroku server

Comment: I am trying to use new Date() with getUTCDate() but it's every time get date form my system date..

Answer (score 1):

The way out would be to create a JSON web service which gives the date and time and call it from angularjs. The web service could be developed in any server side programming language - PHP, ASP.NET, etc..