# How to get server Date and display in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

By using 
var currentDate=new Date();

it is showing local system date..

but, how can i get server date when application is hosted ?

Comment: `var currentDate=new Date()` will always return server date where your application hosted.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the server time as a parameter in the response from your rest calls or create and endpoint that returns the server time.

GET `/your-api-endpoint/time`

Another way is knowing the server timezone( UTC, Europe/Paris, etc), just calculate the time in that timezone inside of your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems incomplete. By Assuming that whatever server side language using be it ASP.NET,PHP, Node js, python or any other server side language.
So you call the get date service from server as service for your angular application.

Let's say you make a service using any server side language to sent you date. In such case you have to call your service using $http service and display it in your html.

Your question seems something similar to this

1. [Ways to use server date in an AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033745/ways-to-use-server-date-in-an-angularjs-application)

   2. [How can I get server date and time in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763683/how-can-i-get-server-date-and-time-in-angularjs)

For further clarification on what you need. Post your code.